# Executar script python ao clicar em botão html

Tags: javascript, html, python, ajax, web-scraping

Preciso  alimentar uma pagina `html` que irá carregar e mostrar o conteúdo de forma dinâmica com `ajax/fetch`. O problema é que preciso pegar esses dados de outro sites que também carregam esse conteúdo através de `ajax`, então não posso fazer as requisições para estas paginas com `ajax` porque elas me retornaram apenas o `html` basico sem as informações que eu preciso.

A solução que encontrei foi fazer o `web scraping` com `python(selenium)` e passar os dados para minha pagina, porém não consigo uma forma de executar meu script `python` de forma que eu não tenha que usar `django`(e alterar todo meu projeto) ou escrever arquivos que fiquem sendo lidos constantemente pelo `python` e congestione os acessos. Vi também algumas coisas relacionadas a `CGI`, mas me parece não ser o que estou procurando pois mostra os elementos dando print nas tags, porém preciso carregar de forma dinâmica, alem de preferir receber esses dados como `json`, `xml` ...

Há alguma forma de executar um script `python` semelhante um script `php` que é chamado na tag `<form>`?

OBS: soluções alternativas podem ajudar mas a principio queria algo com essas ferramentas ou dessa forma.

Comment: Não há necessidade de migrar tudo para o Django. Você pode usar um framework leve como o [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/).

Answer (score 0):

Eu não manjo de python, mas para chamar uma página no backend sem necessariamente acessar ela de forma visível, seria fazendo uma requisição assíncrona, através do AJAX.

Não entendi muito bem a sua necessidade, mas vamos supor que você queira um formulário dinâmico, de acordo com algum retorno, regra, etc... no backend, você pode obter essa informação de uma forma bem fácil acessando essa página com ajax:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

xhr.open("GET", 'sua_pagina'); // envia a requisição a url
xhr.send(null);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // chama uma função quando o documento for carregado 
    if(xhr.readyState === 4) { // verifica se a resposta foi de sucesso
        document.querySelector('form').innerHTML = xhr.responseText // exibe a resposta no seu formulario 
    }
}
```

E você pode ter html puro vindo do seu backend, que vai funcionar e exibir no seu formulário tranquilamente.

Vale lembrar que essa forma de fazer requisições ajax é bem antiga, hoje em dia existem meios mais fáceis e modernos, se você tiver a liberdade, dê uma olhada:

1. [Fetch](https://www.devmedia.com.br/javascript-fetch/41206)
2. [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Usando jQuery por exemplo, você reduz isso tudo pra uma linha se simplesmente só quiser carregar os dados:

```
$('form').load('sua_pagina');
```

Espero ter ajudado!!